# Android "string error" while developing for Android API 19?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

So, I'm developing with Android. I'd like to know, what is wrong with this code? On **activity_main.xml** in the **res/layout** directory, in the Graphical Layout editor, it gives me this error:

```
 Couldn't resolve resource @string/edit_message
 Couldn't resolve resource @string/button_send
```

Strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
  <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
  <string name="button_send">Send</string>
  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
  <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There should be a string defined `edit_message` and `button_send` in `strings.xml`.

Comment: It is defined above and that is in strings.xml only

Comment: Please clean your project and are you using the default Layout folder and the default values folder to put in the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your project and check it out. there is no problem in your code or xml..

```
project->clean
```

Answer (score 1):

cut this code in your mainactivity.xml :

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My First App</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

and put it to `res/values/strings.xml`

Comment: That is written in strings.xml only. He just didnt mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

You've got two root elements in your XML document. Your String resources should go in a file separate to your layout document, usually the file is called "strings.xml.", which would appear in the "values" directory of your project.

Also, you've given your EditText element an id with the name "edit_message". This could clash with your string named "edit_message".

Comment: It wont clash. It would only show a warning and what is written above, that is in strings.xml only

Answer (score 0):

Check if the "fragment_main.xml" and the "strings.xml" tab have a "*" on it, like this "*strings.xml".
It means that you made changes and haven't saved them yet, click on (File > Save) and that's it. At least worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you string references name are spaced correctly in activity xml and Android manifest files them it to be parsed and rendered properly as separate tokens.e.g `@string/buttonX` or `@+id/string/buttonX` are wrong instead space them to " @ string/buttonX " or " @ + id/buttonX "